# How do I remove some/all images in LibreOffice Writer using "find and replace"?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice

Microsoft Word has this nice little feature "find and replace". There I only have to find `^g` and replace with *nothing* and it removes images without using mouse.

I'd like to do the same thing with Libreoffice - I'd rather not use MS Word with Wine on linux just for this. I'd be fine with doing this with macros, or otherwise.

What would be the Libreoffice equivilent of this?

Answer (score 0):

As in the answer to [your question here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/88643/how-do-i-remove-someall-images-in-writer-using-find-and-replace/), use the [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) extension to find images.

Search for `[::Picture::]`, which is one of the choices from the `Extended` drop-down box.  Then click `Find`.

[image: AltSearch]

Note: Unlike the answer by Mike Kaganski, AltSearch 1.4.1 worked fine for me without needing to modify Local1.xba.

This will find one image at a time.  To remove all images at once, it should be fairly simple to adapt [this macro](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/88635/removing-all-draw-objects-from-a-writer-doc/) mentioned in the other answer.